# show the y axis from 0 to 100 in matplotlib plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

If my Temperature data mostly contain 20C and go a bit higher or down then the graph begins from 20C as example and goes to 30C max. I want to go from 0 to 100 regardless what temperature my data has.

I have a second plot that show humidity in % that can go from 0 to 100

I tried set_ylim() but the y axis still begins at 20 and the above is empty with no y numbers on the left.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib import style

#style.use('dark_background')
style.use('fivethirtyeight')

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

def animate(i):
    graph_data = open('example2.txt','r').read()
    lines = graph_data.split('\n')
    xs = []
    ys = []
    yz = []
    for line in lines:
        if len(line) > 1:
            x, y, y2= line.split(',')
            xs.append(x)
            ys.append(float(y)),
            yz.append(float(y2))
    ax1.grid()
    ax1.clear()
    ax1.plot(xs, ys)
    ax1.plot(xs, yz)
    plt.xticks(rotation=45, ha='right')
    plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.30)


ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000)
plt.show()
```

and example2.txt

```
1,20,30
2,20,30
3,20,30
4,20,30
5,20,32
6,23,35
7,23,33
8,23,32
9,24,29
10,25,26
11,24,28
12,23,30
```

Comment: `ax1.set_ylim([0,100])` just **after** `ax1.clear()`

Comment: Yeah I somehow messed it up. I tried it but made it wrong 'ax1.set_ylim(0,100)' without using a tuple or list

Comment: If you think the question I linked to is sufficient for an answer I think you can vote to close as a duplicate.

Comment: I think I need to open a new one because it works in the example but it doesn't work with my data.